# Does anyone know examples of old Danish rowing songs?

Tags: folk

Some friends of mine told me they were on a trip with an old viking dragonboat when some of the girls started to sing some ancient rowing song. 
To be able to have some imagination how that might have sounded I'm now searching for ancient Danish rowing songs.